# Can't show facebook ad with RoboVM from MobiDevelop in Libgdx project

Tags: ios, facebook, libgdx, robovm, facebook-audience-network

I am using the latest mobidevelop fork of RoboVM. I added latest version (2.2.1-SNAPSHOT) of of facebook dependencies in my iOS part of libgdx project. Everything runs fine on iPhone simulator - I can see test ads (interstitial and banners). But there is a problem on real device (iPhone 6 in my case). When I try to load fb interstitial I can only see this error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.ads.sdk Code=1001 "No fill" UserInfo={FBAdErrorDetailKey={msg = "No fill"; }, NSLocalizedDescription=No fill}

I have FB app install and logged on my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve my problem. I checked that code 1001 in FB documentation and it means some of these:

> Error 1001 - No Fill.
>
> May be due to one or more of the following:
> User not logged into Native Facebook App on Mobile Device
> Limit Ad Tracking turned on (iOS)
> Opt out of interest-based ads turned on (Android)
> No Ad Inventory for current user
> Your testing device must have the native Facebook application installed.
> Your application should attempt to make another request after 30 seconds.

So basically, there was no ad for target device/fb user. What I did, I just added that user in fb console as a Test User and now I can see fb ads. Problem solved.